# Remove export to pdf option in Angular ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

Is there a way to remove the option to export to pdf from the ui-grid dropdown menu?  I want to keep the ability to export to csv, but cannot figure out how to remove the pdf feature without removing all export capability.

I edited [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mLMY1IXhNlN25yObDAN6?p=preview) from the docs to remove all of the scripts and JavaScript that are relevant to the pdf exporter.  This effectively disables the functionality, but the option to export to a pdf is still available from the menu.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender', visible: false},
      { field: 'company' }
    ],
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
    exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On line 12 in your plunker add the following grid option (the default value is `true`):

```
 exporterMenuPdf: false,
```

resulting in something like:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: [
      { field: 'name' },
      { field: 'gender', visible: false},
      { field: 'company' }
    ],
    enableGridMenu: true,
    enableSelectAll: true,
    exporterMenuPdf: false, // ADD THIS
    exporterCsvFilename: 'myFile.csv',
    exporterCsvLinkElement: angular.element(document.querySelectorAll(".custom-csv-link-location")),
    onRegisterApi: function(gridApi){
      $scope.gridApi = gridApi;
    }
  };
```

See http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions for all possible options.

Comment: How to remove Export to Excel Option in angular ui-grid

Answer (score 3):

**Use following option to hide Excel Export option**

```
exporterMenuExcel: false
```

[Detail explanation about this parameters](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#!/api/ui.grid.exporter.api:GridOptions)